# No Idea why my code isn't working (Beginner coder)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created a rock, paper, scissors game using Python in which the user can input their choice and then the computer will randomly choose an option itself. Whenever the user enters their entry, my code gives me a `Traceback` error which I have included in the code.

**NOTE:** My code works and executes perfectly in Python IDLE but I am having this trouble only in VS Code and I am trying to figure out why.

I have already tried to configure the JSON File and a copy of that code is present as well.

```
#rock, paper, scissors

from random import randint #to import random numbers



user = input('rock (r), paper (p), scissors (s)?') #Let's the user input something and assigns
    #it to whatever option it picked. So the next line, user will show as r, p, or s. 

print(user, 'against') #Just prints out the user input and the string against.

random = randint (1,3) #Sets the range of the random integer to all numbers between
    #1 and 3, which also includes 1 and 3.

if random == 1:
    computerChoice = 'rock' #Assigning the random integers to a specific string.

elif random == 2:
    computerChoice = 'paper' 

else:
    computerChoice = 'scissors'

#     """COMMENT: The reason why else doesn't have a option like else random == 3:
#         is because else is used when it has to evaluate EVERYTHING else that is left, if you want
#         to make this    user = input('rock (r), paper (p), scissors (s)?') #Let's the user input something and assigns
#         it to whatever option it picked. So the next line, user will show as r, p, or s.""" 



# """COMMENT: The reason why else doesn't have a option like else random == 3:
#         is because else is used when it has to evaluate EVERYTHING else that is left, if you want
#         to make this more restrictive, then just use another elif statement."""

print(computerChoice)

if user == computerChoice: #So it can output if something is a draw. 
    print('Draw!')

elif user == 'rock' and computerChoice == 'scissors': #The colon at the end is important because
    print('You won!')

elif user == 'rock' and computerChoice == 'paper':
    print('You lost!')

elif user == 'paper' and computerChoice == 'rock':
    print('You won!')

elif user == 'paper' and computerChoice == 'scissors':
    print('You lost!')

elif user == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'paper':
    print('You won!')

elif user == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'rock':
    print('You lost!')

    # """COMMENT: The code above consists of If and else statements that makes sure to include all
    # possible outcomes of this game, Since there are not that many outcomes, this works but
    # eventually there should be an easier way of doing this because you cannot just keep writing
    # IF and ELIF statements for several hundred outcomes.
    # The colon at the end of the statements is important because you are executing something.
    # """
```

---

JSON File Config:

```
//{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387


    {
        "version": "3.5",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Python: Current File",
                "program": "${file}",
                "console": "internalConsole"
            }
        ]
    }
```

---

ERROR MESSAGE OUTPUT:

rock (r), paper (p), scissors (s)?
rock
not available

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Users\yoush\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 284, in _on_run
    self.process_net_command_json(self.global_debugger_holder.global_dbg, json_contents)

  File "c:\Users\yoush\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 157, in process_net_command_json
    cmd = on_request(py_db, request)

  File "c:\Users\yoush\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 559, in on_evaluate_request
    py_db, request, thread_id)

  File "c:\Users\yoush\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_api.py", line 385, in request_exec_or_evaluate_json
    thread_id, internal_evaluate_expression_json, request, thread_id)

  File "c:\Users\yoush\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 873, in post_method_as_internal_command
    self.post_internal_command(internal_cmd, thread_id)

  File "c:\Users\yoush\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 877, in post_internal_command
    queue = self.get_internal_queue(thread_id)

  File "c:\Users\yoush\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 864, in get_internal_queue
    if thread_id.startswith('__frame__'):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: I think the `input` is causing some issues, try replacing that with a hardcoded string and see if it helps?

Comment: Your Error message output doesn't seem to have any relation with your code, it seems like it had occurred due to wrong config in IDE Files

Comment: Vasu, do you know how I can possibly fix that problem?

Answer (score -1):

Use else in second last line instead of elif. It worked for me.

```
elif user == 'paper' and computerChoice == 'scissors':
    print('You lost!')

elif user == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'paper':
    print('You won!')

else:
    print('You lost!')
```

Comment: `input()` function has a return type of `str` by default, why bother explicitly converting it to string then?

Comment: Assuming you are referring to [python-3.x], returned data from input statements is always a string value (no encoding). Even if you needed an encoding, then the function would be `data.encode(encoding)`

Comment: I just did this but I still have the same problem.

Comment: You might instead need to use `.encode('utf-8')` (`b'some_string'`) or `B'some_string'` or `r'some_string'`, look at the python documentation for the `str` encodings

Comment: Where do I make these changes?

Comment: At the second last line of code.  instead of  writing  **elif user == 'scissors' and computerChoice == 'rock':
    print('You lost!')**       write      **else:
    print('You lost!')**

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the IDEs you're using, but I suspect the difference is that one of them is interpreting your code with python 3 and the other is interpreting it with python 2.7. There's a major difference in how input works between these two revisions:

- In python3, the input() function returns a string (which is the behavior you want in this case)
- In python 2.7, the input() function evaluates what the user types as a python command (which is very rarely what you want, and is definitely not what you want in this case). If you want to get a string from the user in python 2.7, use the raw_input() function instead.

Comment: Just tried this, I made sure that both IDEs are using Python 3 and above, none of them are using Python 2.7.